# Sliding Drawer left to right and i want use all activities

Tags: android

I want to use sliding drawer from left to right ?
So can you tell me anybody how it is possible? and also use this drawer to all activity in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Use the concept of viewpager.You can find doc and example below...

[doc](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

[Example](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-using)

Answer (score 0):

Check that library. API 6+ (even less, not quite sure)
https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib
You can attach a layer to any part of the screen with the addition that you can swipe the layout directly in and out, unlike the SlidingDrawer in which you just can drag from a small piece of UI (drawer).

You could also use the new NavigationDrawer pattern from Google.
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html